# strange behavior of python function time.time()

Tags: python

consider the following python function:

```
def prandom():
    t = time.time()
    s = t - int(t)
    s = str('{0:.16f}'.format(s))
    print s
    s = int(s[5])
    print(s)
    return s
```

the naive intention is to get a pseudorandom digit.
However: how do you explain that, no matter how many times I run the function (on a Windows 10 machine) I get either a 0 or a 9? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I get all ten digits from this, on OS X. Something weird about what times are returned in Windows?

Comment: I am getting all ten digits on Windows too.

Comment: Works for me on 2.7.10.  BTW, you don't need the `str()` around the `format` (but it won't affect the output).

Comment: `time.time()` precision is platform dependent and by its own [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) it doesn't guarantee precision of more than one second. If you're using Python 2.x on Windows, use `time.clock()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some modification in your code better modify your function:

```
def prandom():
    t = time.time()
    return str("{0:.16f}".format(t))[-1]
```

This will give all the values

**Best way to generate random number is to use random function**

import random

```
a = random.randint(0, 9) # two argument will generate number between those numbers
print a # random digit from 0 to 9
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
8
```